# How to give suggestions when typing the first letter of a folder in lineEdit leads to the folders starting with this letter in pyQt4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I am developing a GUI using pyqt4 where it has a lineEdit and browse button.

[image]

So the user can either browse or enter the path. When the user starts typing, how do I give suggestions for the same folder starting with this letter something like in windows file explorer?

[image]
Is there any module in pyqt4 to do that?

Comment: [QCompleter example](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-tools-completer-example.html) and [PyQt example](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/tools/customcompleter).

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro

Answer (score 0):

Just three lines of code worked like charm to achieve the above functionality

```
    completer = QCompleter(self)
    completer.setModel(QDirModel(completer))
    lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)
```